# Extract Numbers from a field without a stored function

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to extract from a String part containing only "allowed" characters like digits?

The only requirement is that it needs to be done inline, without a stored function.

Is it even possible?

Comment: So is it like char column in some table, or is it a variable? Do you know which characters could be in this string?

Comment: Sounds like it should be possible using PATINDEX and SUBSTRING. Can you show some table and sample data. Whether or not it's a good idea is a matter of the situation because it'll not be high performance and could easily be complex to read and maintain

Comment: I have a field in the database which contains unformatted UE tax number like PL777-111-12-95, I need to extract PL7771111295, without a stored function. There can also be spaces and such. I need to preserve digits and letters.

Comment: Have you considered using `replace()` to remove the stuff you don't want instead? `replace(replace(replace(YourColumn, '.', ''), '-', ''), ' ', '')`.  Just keep on stacking replace until you have removed all the characters you don't want in there.